# Why return true or false from functions?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm currently working through the *Single Page Web Applications* by Mikowski and Powell. After working through the simple tutorial in Chapter 1, I am confused on why it is necessary to `return true` and `return false` in the `toggleSlider()`, `onClickSlider()`, and `initModule()` functions.

What is the added benefit of doing so? When I ran the below code without the `return true` and `return false`, it worked exactly the same as with the return statements.

What is an appropriate situation for which having these return statements is actually beneficial and necessary?

```
var spa = (function($) {
  var configMap = {
      extended_height: 434,
      extended_title: 'Click to retract',
      retracted_height: 16,
      retracted_title: 'Click to extend',
      template_html: '<div class="spa-slider"><\/div>'
    },
    $chatSlider,
    toggleSlider, onClickSlider, initModule;

  toggleSlider = function() {
    var slider_height = $chatSlider.height();

    if (slider_height === configMap.retracted_height) {

      $chatSlider
        .animate({
          height: configMap.extended_height
        })
        .attr('title', configMap.extended_title);
      return true;

    } else if (slider_height === configMap.extended_height) {
      $chatSlider
        .animate({
          height: configMap.retracted_height
        })
        .attr('title', configMap.retracted_title);
      return true;

    }

    console.log("Nothing to extend or retract. No events fired.");
    return false;
  };

  onClickSlider = function(event) {
    console.log("Calling onClickSlider click event");
    toggleSlider();
    return false;
  };

  initModule = function($container) {
    $container.html(configMap.template_html);

    $chatSlider = $container.find('.spa-slider');

    $chatSlider
      .attr('title', configMap.retracted_title)
      .click(onClickSlider);

    return true;
  };

  return {
    initModule: initModule
  };

}(jQuery));

jQuery(document).ready(
  function() {
    spa.initModule(jQuery('#spa'));
  }
);

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #777;
}
#spa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.spa-slider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #f00;
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="spa">
        <div class="spa-slider"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, these return values serve no purpose. I suspect it's just the author's personal style, he likes to have explicit return values. `toggleSlider` uses the return value to indicate whether it did anything, which could be useful for debugging in the console, although it also uses `console.log()` for the same purpose.

Comment: @nhgrif I apologize. I retract my reference to Code Review.  My point still stands though that this doesn't appear to be on topic here either, as it's not asking about a particular issue the poster is having trouble finding a resolution for.

Comment: @Claies Then I recommend finding a close reason and voting for it, and perhaps downvote it?  You're certain this question is off-topic for SO, yet it has zero downvotes and zero close votes.  To me, this question seems perfectly fine for SO, really.

Comment: @nhgrif  -- my apologies on the structure of my question. Only just started using SO recently. Will pay more careful attention in the future. Thank you for your help and feedback. Best!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often, in event handlers, returning false is a way to tell the event to not actually fire. So, for example, in an onsubmit case, this would mean that the form is not submitted.

In your example `return true;` will make the animation occur, while  `return false;` won't.

Alternatively, you can do [e.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) instead of `return false;`.

Comment: But most of these functions are not event handlers.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you for response. This clears up my concerns. Best!

Answer (score 4):

Return values like this in Javascript functions are often used to indicate success or failure. You can create a simple flow-control structure by doing something like:

```
var doSomething = function() {
    if (error) { 
        return false; 
    } else { 
        return true; 
   }
};

if (doSomething()) { 
    doSomethingElse(); 
} else { 
    console.log("There was an error!"); 
}
```

That said, it's rarely a good idea to use this for anything other than a quick demo. `return false` is notorious for producing unexpected results when used purely in this manner - there's almost always a better option to achieve your goal (unless your goal is returning a boolean value!). If you just need to escape an active function, you can just use `return;`.

In your specific code, `toggleSlider()` appears to be returning these values to indicate activity, while `onClickSlider()` is using `return false` in place of `e.preventDefault()`, as Nicholas mentioned in their answer. You can read more about why this is often a bad idea here: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Great article reference. Thanks so much. Best!

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you are looking for a hard-set rule where there really isn't one.

You ask "Why" this rule exists when it really doesn't.

You are still reading **chapter 1** of Mikowski and Powell's *Single Page Web Applications* and I am very happy they get you to think and to notice your function's returned value.

There are many possible returned values - `true` and `false`are just two very common and very important options.

In more advanced functions you might find yourself returning `self` or an `object` of any number of different return value's - all according to the application's architecture and what you need.

For instance, in Object Oriented Programming, it is becoming more and more common to return `self` for simple functions. This allows you to chain different functions in one line... but what does Object Oriented Programming have to do with chapter 1?

I recommend you allow yourself more time and experience. For now, I would suggest that you trust the process. Mikowski and Powell are doing their best to feed you a lot of knowledge... but they have to divide it into smaller bites and pieces.

Good Luck!

Comment: Downvote as this is in no way an attempt at answering the question. It's a nice sentiment though! Maybe just leave an encouraging comment instead?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your feedback. However, this does answer the question by stating that the premise of the question is wrong. The question is "Why X is true" and the answer is "X isn't true".

Comment: Hi @Alex - please see my comment and reconsider.

Comment: While I agree that this is a deeper issue than OP (or myself, even) can fully appreciate at the moment, I don't believe "trust the process" is ever an appropriate answer for a technical question. We'll have to agree to disagree on this one, respectfully. :)